# What is the alternate to SA account in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, permissions

My client is currently using SQL Server for their app. At this time they are using SA account everywhere. For security reasons we need to disable the SA account. The solution I've is create another power user (not admin), like standard user and root user. The development only needs access for CRUD operations. So, what should be the rights/roles/privileges for this new account? We need to replicate the same model to the internet server where only read rights are required (from viewer's end). How do I go about it?

Two different versions, 2008 R2 and 2012.

Answer (score 3):

On your development server, you can grant the standard users the `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader` roles. You probably want to grant the `db_owner` role to the power user. As these are database level roles, you have to repeat this for each of your databases. Regarding the web server, you should create a limited user that only has been granted the `db_datareader` role.

As the `sa` login is hardcoded to be a member of the sysadmin server, you can't limit the permission of this account. The best way to migrate is to replace all the connection string you can find and then finally disable the `sa` account.

Comment: Connection strings are using 'sa' for login. sa also has db ownership. How do i change that smoothly or with minimum conflicts?

Comment: You need to change all the connection strings and then disable the `sa` account.

Comment: Will try this and update you on this.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to create an equivalent login to 'sa' and then disable the 'sa' account.

It is also good practice to create login/user combinations that allow you to follow a practice of assigning least privilege to any logins to your system. This not only provides you with a better audit trail, for seeing who is making changes to the schema, but it also provides better security.

The 'sa' user has db_owner privileges on all databases on your instance, to create the equivalent login do the following. Create a login with some , grant the sysadmin role to the login, map a user to all of your databases and add the db_owner role to the user.

For your other users create login/user combinations that only have access to those database objects/operations that they need.

After you've created these login(s), you will be able to assign the needed permissions. In the environment the user is added to the db_reader group and then explicit permissions are granted revoked on a per object basis.

You can streamline multiple users by creating a new database role and managing the granted/revoked privileges there and simply adding the users that need those permissions to that database role.

Comment: Here's what I did:
I split the powers (fixed server roles) of SA in three accounts.
1. An account for devs/internet server - diskadmin,dbcreator. Then disabled view any database and made this account the owner of the only database needed.
2. Another account that would be able to perform maintenance activities. securityadmin, serveradmin
3. Third account with sysadmin role.

Comment: The account with the sysadmin role has full rights on everything I believe. So you've really got things divided in two and then a 'sa' equivalent account. [The dbo user account is frequently confused with the db_owner fixed database role. The scope of db_owner is a database; the scope of sysadmin is the whole server. Membership in the db_owner role does not confer dbo user privileges.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I checked and I can tell that although the sysadmin can view databases it can't modify them.  The other dev account is mapped to just one db, by making it dbo.

Comment: @swapHow did you check that exactly? The sysadmin role is the "root" user for SQL Server. I just checked to make sure I wasn't mistaken. Created a new login, did nothing other than assign it the sysadmin role and mapped it to the database. I'm able to do everything under that login.

Comment: I didn't map it to any db. I could see databases but not actually access them. I guess that's weird.

Comment: @swap That's why. When creating a login, you need to map it to a user in order to have it be able to really interact with a database. If the login has the sysadmin role it will have "root" privileges on any database you have it mapped to.

Comment: So it's a good thing then. I can do everything else but db ops, which in my opinion is good. What do you think?

Comment: For what you're trying to accomplish it would probably be better to create a role and grant/revoke operations you'd like the login/user to be able to perform. For instance you could create login a and assign it membership in db_reader. Then map it to a user in your database. Then you would add your custom role to that user. In this way you can get very granular control. Using more explicit grants/revokes than implicit ones. [Here's a handy link that show how things flow](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11842.sql-server-database-engine-permission-posters.aspx)